# Download an image to local storage in Metro style apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

In WinRT / C#, How do I download an image to a local folder to support caching of an online catalogue for offline use? is there a way to directly download the images and link the control to get them from the cache as a fallback?

```
    var downloadedimage = await HttpWebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync();
    StorageFile imgfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                        "localfile.png", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

What do I do next to store downloadedimage as localfile.jpg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the code below from the HttpClient sample for Windows 8 solves the issue

```
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Get, resourceAddress);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await rootPage.httpClient.SendAsync(request,
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

httpClient is a HttpClient, and its BaseAddress needs to be set a the server folder of your resource. we can then do this to convert that to an image source (if that's what we're downloading)

```
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = 
        new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
    writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    imagecontrol.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
```

or this to write it to file

```
    var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
         filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
    writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    writer.DetachStream();
    await fs.FlushAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        var response = await HttpWebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync();
        List<Byte> allBytes = new List<byte>();
        using (Stream imageStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4000)) > 0)
            {
                allBytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
            }
        }
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                    "localfile.png", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, allBytes.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks this is an easy solution and it works. I'm working a soluction using Metro App for Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download a file represented by a URL, the easiest way is to use the BackgroundDownloader class.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx) page for more information on how to use the background downloader.

Comment: I need to implement a caching mechanic to run my app in Offline mode, nothing too complex. this might unnecessarily complicate

Answer (score 0):

GetResponseAsync will give you a WebResponse file not the image:

```
Stream imageStream = downloadedimage.GetResponseStream();
```

Then you can write to the image file:

```
byte[] imageData = new byte[imageStream.Length];
using(StreamReader reader = new Streamreader(imageStream))
{
    reader.ReadBytes(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
}
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(imgfile, imageData);
```

Comment: We need to change ReadBytes to reader.BaseStream.Read, but I can't confirm if its working yet - will update

Comment: tried  var downloadedimage = await HttpWebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync(); with GetResponseStreamAsync(), it didn't work - what do we need to change?

Comment: @JayKannan try Sofian's code for reading the stream in a buffered fashion.

Comment: You probably need to write a request before you will get a response.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18034/HttpWebRequest-Response-in-a-Nutshell-Part-1

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

By default Bitmap Images are cached by WinRT with no intervention required by the developer.